# How to get better performance with Strassen Algorithm than the naive approach without a cut off point?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, matrix-multiplication, strassen

I'm trying to test the naive and Strassen method for matrix multiplication.

However, the Strassen algorithm works way slower than the naive approach. For a 1024 sized matrix, the naive approach completes in 3542ms while Strassen in 83602ms. (with Strassen not using cut off/naive approach)
Here is the Strassen code that I'm using. LEAF SIZE is the number where it switches to the naive approach:

```java
int n = A.length;

if (n <= LEAF_SIZE) {
    return ikjAlgorithm(A, B);
} else {
    // initializing the new sub-matrices
    int newSize = n / 2;
    int[][] a11 = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] a12 = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] a21 = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] a22 = new int[newSize][newSize];

    int[][] b11 = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] b12 = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] b21 = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] b22 = new int[newSize][newSize];

    int[][] aResult = new int[newSize][newSize];
    int[][] bResult = new int[newSize][newSize];

    // dividing the matrices in 4 sub-matrices:
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++) {
            a11[i][j] = A[i][j]; // top left
            a12[i][j] = A[i][j + newSize]; // top right
            a21[i][j] = A[i + newSize][j]; // bottom left
            a22[i][j] = A[i + newSize][j + newSize]; // bottom right

            b11[i][j] = B[i][j]; // top left
            b12[i][j] = B[i][j + newSize]; // top right
            b21[i][j] = B[i + newSize][j]; // bottom left
            b22[i][j] = B[i + newSize][j + newSize]; // bottom right
        }
    }

    // Calculating p1 to p7:
    aResult = add(a11, a22);
    bResult = add(b11, b22);
    int[][] p1 = strassenR(aResult, bResult);
    // p1 = (a11+a22) * (b11+b22)

    aResult = add(a21, a22); // a21 + a22
    int[][] p2 = strassenR(aResult, b11); // p2 = (a21+a22) * (b11)

    bResult = subtract(b12, b22); // b12 - b22
    int[][] p3 = strassenR(a11, bResult);
    // p3 = (a11) * (b12 - b22)

    bResult = subtract(b21, b11); // b21 - b11
    int[][] p4 = strassenR(a22, bResult);
    // p4 = (a22) * (b21 - b11)

    aResult = add(a11, a12); // a11 + a12
    int[][] p5 = strassenR(aResult, b22);
    // p5 = (a11+a12) * (b22)

    aResult = subtract(a21, a11); // a21 - a11
    bResult = add(b11, b12); // b11 + b12
    int[][] p6 = strassenR(aResult, bResult);
    // p6 = (a21-a11) * (b11+b12)

    aResult = subtract(a12, a22); // a12 - a22
    bResult = add(b21, b22); // b21 + b22
    int[][] p7 = strassenR(aResult, bResult);
    // p7 = (a12-a22) * (b21+b22)

    // calculating c21, c21, c11 e c22:
    int[][] c12 = add(p3, p5); // c12 = p3 + p5
    int[][] c21 = add(p2, p4); // c21 = p2 + p4

    aResult = add(p1, p4); // p1 + p4
    bResult = add(aResult, p7); // p1 + p4 + p7
    int[][] c11 = subtract(bResult, p5);
    // c11 = p1 + p4 - p5 + p7

    aResult = add(p1, p3); // p1 + p3
    bResult = add(aResult, p6); // p1 + p3 + p6
    int[][] c22 = subtract(bResult, p2);
    // c22 = p1 + p3 - p2 + p6

    // Grouping the results obtained in a single matrix:
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newSize; j++) {
            C[i][j] = c11[i][j];
            C[i][j + newSize] = c12[i][j];
            C[i + newSize][j] = c21[i][j];
            C[i + newSize][j + newSize] = c22[i][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

```java
private static int[][] add(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
    int n = A.length;
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}

private static int[][] subtract(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
    int n = A.length;
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] - B[i][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

With the leaf size at around 32, it does indeed perform faster(that is the cut-off point where the naive algorithm kicks in)

This is in Java language. The code is from the internet, however more or less all of the implementations are similar.

Is it not possible to beat naive with just Strassen without a cut off point?
Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

***EDIT*** Added add and subtract methods.

***EDIT2*** From the code is the biggest overhead from the creating of new submatrices? If so, what method could be applied to remove as much overhead as possible? If nothing can be done in java I'm not against using c++.

**EDIT3** Could anyone suggest a method on how to reduce the memory allocation that used here? Would be grateful for the suggestions.

Comment: Off-topic: is this just for fun or do you expect some gain in your work? I don't think any general-purpose code does use non-naive matmul: all (incl. all hyped deep-learning applications) will use some naive-matmul based BLAS-backend. Probably because it's hard to make it work. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807065/where-is-strassens-matrix-multiplication-useful). When trying to approach real-world performance, it probably does not help to try java either. The `int[][]` stuff alone looks terrible (array of objects) in terms of caching.

Comment: @sascha This is for an assigment to compare Strassen and naive approach.

Comment: You can find some practical measurements in [this site](http://www.fastmmw.com/), devoted to fast matrix multiplication.